# What is interest to use an embedded Tomcat server when testing web layer in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-annotations

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two annotations...

this one, which makes starting a real embedded server at starting

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

and this one, which do not start any http server..

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
```

Of course, when I use the first on `(SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`, I got this log at starting:

```
2023-12-16T16:07:40.816+01:00  INFO 25939 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 0 (http)
2023-12-16T16:07:40.826+01:00  INFO 25939 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-16T16:07:40.826+01:00  INFO 25939 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.16]
2023-12-16T16:07:40.879+01:00  INFO 25939 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-16T16:07:40.881+01:00  INFO 25939 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1677 ms
```

So, my question is: what is the interest of using an embedded http server when testing as results are the same.

To be precise, I use this kind of code:

```
// results are the same, with WebEnvironment.MOCK
// or WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT !!    
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class TestExample {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/first")
                        .accept(MediaType.ALL))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("mocked body")
                );
    }

}
```